# IF statement in Word document is always True

Tags: ms-word

I've created a .docx document. This document contains many quick parts fields, because the document is part of a SharePoint Online Workflow, where a document is created and values inside the document are filled by the SP Workflow.

In my document, I've created an IF statement:

```
{ IF "[Optional_Price]" <> "€ 0,00" "*INSIDE THIS DOUBLE QUOTES I'VE INSERTED A TABLE*" "" }
```

`[Optional_Price]` is a Quick Part field. It is filled by SharePoint Workflow, as a formatted currency.

So, this could be a realistic scenario:

```
{ IF "€ 10,00" <> "€ 0,00" "*INSIDE THIS DOUBLE QUOTES I'VE INSERTED A TABLE*" "" }
```

Document is always created with table in it, even if `[Optional_Price]` is set as "€ 0,00", like the condition is always true.

Is the IF statement not correct?

Comment: We need more information. Insert only the "Quick Par field" somewhere then Press Alt+F9 to display *all* field codes in the document. How does the Quick Part field look, now? My best guess is that you haven't actually inserted the field, only a text representation...

Comment: @CindyMeister Hi! If I insert the field in another part of the document and I press ALT+F9 it keeps showing up as [Optional_Price], instead, the IF statement disappears completely, except for the table.

Comment: Press Alt+F9 a couple of times to make sure you're toggling... Ah, and if you click into Option_Price do you see a "box" around it? (I can't test your scenario, not having SharePoint set up for this. I can't remember if these are *fields* or *content controls*)

Comment: It looks like these are content controls, not fields. Content controls can't be used in IF fields. Try asking this in a venue that specializes in end-user questions such as Super User or Microsoft Answers - you're more likely to find people with experience in this area in such a place. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Advanced field code combinations can fall into that category, but this isn't that...